# Insert value into an array within an array

Tags: python, arrays, append

So I am try to figure out how to add items to an array within a array I have. I am first using a while loop to scan barcodes into an array. Then I am the number of items I scanned and creating an individual array for each separate one.

```
serial_numbers = []
while True:
    s = input("Scan Serial Number: ")
    if s == "done":
        break
    serial_numbers.append(s)
print("Here is the list of serial numbers:")
print(serial_numbers)

inventory = [[i] for i in serial_numbers]
print(inventory)
```

Output:

```
[['CNX000000000952708'], ['CNX000000000952705']]
```

I then want to take the value I get from:

```
print("Select Equipment Type")
equipment_type = input("1: Desktop \n2: Dock Monitor \n3: Docking Station \n4: Laptop \n5: Monitor \n6: Printer \n7: Projector \n8: Scanner \n9: Surface Keyboard \n10: Surface Pen \n11: Tablet \n12: Tiny-in-One Monitor\n")
if equipment_type == "1":
    equipment_type = "Desktop"
elif equipment_type == "2":
    equipment_type = "Dock Monitor"
elif equipment_type == "3":
    equipment_type = "Docking Station"
elif equipment_type == "4":
    equipment_type = "Laptop"
```

and add it to each of the arrays I have in the inventory array. For example:
[['CNX000000000952708', Desktop], ['CNX000000000952705', Desktop]]

My goal is to be create a script where:

1. User with select the equipment_type from preset choices.
2. User with select the equipment_model from present choices.
3. User will select if the equipment is on a lease or not (true/fasle).
4. User will scan each item without have to re run script each time for each item.

For example: I want to scan 12 laptops into my inventory db. I will set the equipment_type to "laptop" (or choice 4), then set the equipment_model to "Dell XP1" (or choice 3), then select y/n for lease, then scan all the serial numbers for each laptop. The output should be 12 individual arrays/lists for each laptop:

```
[serial_number1, laptop, Dell XP1, true]
[serial_number2, laptop, Dell XP1, true]
[serial_number3, laptop, Dell XP1, true]
[serial_number4, laptop, Dell XP1, true]
[serial_number5, laptop, Dell XP1, true]
[serial_number6, laptop, Dell XP1, true]
```

The only thing that would be different for each array/list would be the serial number...the equipment_type/models and lease would all be identical.

Full code of what I currently have below:

```
serial_numbers = []
while True:
    s = input("Scan Serial Number: ")
    if s == "done":
        break
    serial_numbers.append(s)
print("Here is the list of serial numbers:")
print(serial_numbers)

inventory = [[i] for i in serial_numbers]
print(inventory)

print("Select Equipment Type")
equipment_type = input("1: Desktop \n2: Dock Monitor \n3: Docking Station \n4: Laptop \n5: Monitor \n6: Printer \n7: Projector \n8: Scanner \n9: Surface Keyboard \n10: Surface Pen \n11: Tablet \n12: Tiny-in-One Monitor\n")
if equipment_type == "1":
    equipment_type = "Desktop"
elif equipment_type == "2":
    equipment_type = "Dock Monitor"
elif equipment_type == "3":
    equipment_type = "Docking Station"
elif equipment_type == "4":
    equipment_type = "Laptop"
elif equipment_type == "5":
    equipment_type = "Monitor"
elif equipment_type == "6":
    equipment_type = "Printer"
elif equipment_type == "7":
    equipment_type = "Projector"
elif equipment_type == "8":
    equipment_type = "Scanner"
elif equipment_type == "9":
    equipment_type = "Surface Keyboard"
elif equipment_type == "10":
    equipment_type = "Surface Pen"
elif equipment_type == "11":
    equipment_type = "Tablet"
elif equipment_type == "12":
    equipment_type = "Tiny-in-One Monitor"


print("Select Equipment Model")
equipment_model = input("1: P15s Gen1 \n2: P15s Gen2 \n3: P53s \n4: Surface Pro 7 \n5: Thinkbook 15 G2 \n6: Thinkcentre M75Q \n7: Thinkvision P24h-20 \n8: Thinkvision T2454p \n9: Thinkvision T24i-20\n")
if equipment_model == "1":
    equipment_model = "P15s Gen1"
elif equipment_model == "2":
    equipment_model = "P15s Gen2"
elif equipment_model == "3":
    equipment_model = "P53s"
elif equipment_model == "4":
    equipment_model = "Surface Pro 7"
elif equipment_model == "5":
    equipment_model = "Thinkbook 15 G2"
elif equipment_model == "6":
    equipment_model = "Thinkcentre M75Q"
elif equipment_model == "7":
    equipment_model = "Thinkvision P24h-20"
elif equipment_model == "8":
    equipment_model = "Thinkvision T2454p"
elif equipment_model == "9":
    equipment_model = "Thinkvision T24i-20"
print(equipment_model)

print("----")
lease = input("Is this a lease? Y/N\n")
if lease == "Y":
    lease = True
elif lease == "N":
    lease = False
```

Comment: At what point do you request the equipment type? Within the while loop? Or in a separate loop after collecting inventory array? Or just once and because it's gonna be an identical value for all items?

Comment: Just once, It will be identical. Ideally I collect the "equipment_type", "equipment_model", and "lease" first...then scan all the serial numbers in, since the preliminary info will all be the same.

Comment: I am working towards then inserting the data directly into a MS Access db

Comment: Do you want to _update_ the existing `serial_numbers` list to include the equipment type, or do you want to _create_ the list a different way so that it includes the equipment type from the start?

Comment: Can you help us a bit and make it clearer, best on a quick glance: what is your input, the output you get and which output you want.

Comment: I just edited my post, hopefully that makes things more clear.

Comment: BTW, what you call "array" is not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/array.html). It's a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#list). Those two types are different.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `inventory` list, and add "Laptop" (or whatever value you like) to each sub-list.

```
for sublist in inventory:
    sublist.append('Laptop')
```

Comment: I am trying to pull the value directly from the equipment_list variable so the user doesnt have to type in...just select a number

Comment: Your code does not contain a variable named `equipment_list`, so it's very hard to understand what you want...

Comment: I updated my post with an example of what I am looking to do.